# Django - How to pull out a book from genre model

Tags: django, django-views, django-filter

Im studying django. I'm trying to get every book per genre that is connected to my genre model.

here's my genre model.

```
class Genre(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

     def __str__(self):
     return self.name
```

and here's my book model.

````
class Book(models.Model):
```some fields```
      genre = models.ManyToManyField(Genre, help_text="Select a genre for this book")


     def display_genre(self):
         return ', '.join([genre.name for genre in self.genre.all()[:3]])

     display_genre.short_description = 'Genre'



     def __str__(self):
         return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('book-detail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})
````

and here's my attempt to pull out the book from genre with its detail

```
def genre(request):
    genres = Genre.objects.all()

    context = {
         'genres': genres
     }
    return render(request, 'catalog/genre_list.html', context)
```

Comment: Read [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/). I don't understand your attempt, there's just a list of `Genre` objects, where are you trying to get the related `Book`s?

Comment: actually it's a failed attempt. i don't have any idea how to get books that listed under genre models.

Comment: read the link, it will explain you how to fetch many-to-many relationships

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a `Genre` instance `genre`, then the books associated with it are:

```
genre.book_set.all()  # set related_name in your model if you want this to be genre.books.all()
```

So if you have a list of genres, like you're passing in your context, you could do this in your template to display all the books per genre:

```html
{% for genre in genres %}
   Books for {{ genre }}:
   {% for book in genre.book_set.all %} 
       {{ book.title }} <br>
   {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Note that your view is only fetching the genres, so when the template renders, Django has to perform one database query for each genre to fetch all the books. If you want to avoid that and have only one extra query to fetch them all in one go, change the query in your view:

```
genres = Genre.objects.all().prefetch_related('book')
```

Comment: this is what i've been looking for.. actually I've already did this but i messed up in the part of book_set.all

Comment: should i change view to class based view for easy pagination?

Comment: I can't answer that question easily. it really depends on what you're trying to achieve, how it should look like, what you're going to paginate on (genres or books?). better ask a new question when you try something and hit a specific issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get all of the books from a genre, but the genre does not know what books it includes.

You can query for all sets of books that have specific genres by doing the following:

```
Books.objects.filter(genre__name='Science')
```

Be sure to use the double underscore between your object class name and the attribute it has.

Comment: what if i have many genres, romance, horror etc. Im gonna do it that way many times? and what if i added new genre in admin panel?